# Update SQL datetime column with oldest values of another table column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `projects` table with a timestamp column `started_at` and a `tasks` table with the columns `project_id` and `started_at`.

Is there a way to mass update with a single query the `projects` rows to set `started_at` with the oldest `started_at` values from the `tasks` table?

For instance if the table `tasks` has the rows:

```
project_id | started_at
1          | 2010-01-01
1          | 2015-01-01
2          | 2000-01-01
2          | 2020-01-01
```

running the query would update the `projects` table like this

```
id | started_at
1  | 2010-01-01
2  | 2000-01-01
```

I use PostgreSQL.

Comment: No, I don't to remove any rows. Just update rows of the `projects` table, based on values of the `tasks` table.

Comment: Because before running the query it had already only 2 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE projects 
SET started_at = OldestDate
FROM
(
   SELECT project_id, MIN(started_at) AS OldestDate
   FROM tasks
   GROUP BY project_id
) AS t 
WHERE t.project_id = id;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/574b9/1)